# User permissions API in CQ

Tags: aem

Consider creating a standalone java program for creating user/group with the access permission.
So my question is, Is there any APIs available for setting user-permissions in CQ ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [JCR access control management](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/16_Access_Control_Management.html) api that can be used to read and assign access control policies.  There is also a jackrabbit [UserManager](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/UserManager.html) accessible from within CQ for creating users/groups.

There are some code examples on the [User Management](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/UserManagement) page of the JackRabbit wiki.

Essentially, you need to cast the JcrSession to a JackRabbitSession and call getUserManager() on that.

```
JackrabbitSession js = (JackrabbitSession) session;
final UserManager userManager = session.getUserManager();
final User user = userManager.createUser(userName, userName);
session.save();
```

There are a couple of ways of getting the session, one way is to get the resource resolver from the request and [adaptTo](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/sling-adapters.html) a Session from there.

```
Session session = slingHttpServletRequest.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
```

Finally, there is a [Sling HTTP api for managing users & groups](http://sling.apache.org/site/managing-users-and-groups-jackrabbitusermanager.html).

Comment: I am getting a class cast exception while casting the jcr session to JackrabbitSession. Is there any other way to get the UserManager object?