# Getting a JackrabbitSession object from a JCR session object

Tags: aem, jcr, jackrabbit

My goal is to get a JackrabbitSession from a JCR session in a standalone java application. I spent hours on it but can't find a working example.

A few post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580283/user-permissions-api-in-cq) for example are implying it is possible to cast from a JCR session to a JackrabbitSession as follows but it actually does not work and throws a ClassCastException.

```
Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");
session = repository.login( new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()), "crx.default");

JackrabbitSession js = (JackrabbitSession) session;
final UserManager userManager = session.getUserManager();
final User user = userManager.createUser(userName, userName);
session.save();
```

The reason I want the native JackrabbitSession is because as in the above code I want to access the UserManager object. In my use case the JCR repository resides in an AEM instance on which I would like to create/delete users.

Thx in advance

Comment: You are probably going to have a way easier time creating a `Servlet` in AEM that exposes a simple (REST) API which can be used by your standalone application. Easier but maybe not as flexible might be to just use the out of the box features of Sling to create/read/update/delete users. All you have to do is issue HTTP requests: http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/adobe-cq5-aem-curl-commands/#AEM%20User%20Management%20cURL%20commands

Answer (score 3):

You can get UserManager by adapting resourceResolver :

**userManager = resolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);**

Comment: How do i get that resolver from a java standalone app(my use case)?

Comment: @isaac.hazan if your in sling concept you could use factory to create resourceResolver, or maybe inject it somehow

Comment: @isaac.hazan if you in context of SlingHttpServletRequest you can easly get it from request

Comment: As i said in my comment above. Getting the resolver is easy if i am in Sling, the whole point of the question is that i am trying to do that from a stand alone application. Even the answer provided is off topic because it assumes as i am in a sling container.